# asynchronous use of .css jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hey I was wondering if anyone could help me with some basic javascript. Is it possible to use the jquery .css to use asynchronous callbacks to stagger changes to css?

E.g.

```
 jQuery("#topbar").css({transition: "background-color 10s ease", background: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)"});
            //jQuery("#topbar").css({transition: "background-color 10s ease", background: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)"});
```

In this example can I alter the first function to become asysnchronous so that it runs the second commented function in a callback function?

Thanks

Comment: I understood what you want, but the way you put it is kind of confusing. You don't `use the jquery .css`, you `apply styles/transitions at runtime with jQuery`

Comment: That's not what asynchronous means. Asynchronous means that one thing does not have to wait for another -- that their run times are not synchronized. You want the opposite.

Comment: Use `.animate()` to queue css changes

Comment: Can you more clearly explain what you want to happen visually.

Comment: Just wanted to get a flash in flash out effect. My experience with asynchronous programming is that the only way to ensure sequential logic is through callbacks. Even loops must use callbacks. More like recursion I suppose. .animate() is probably the best option just have v limited front-end experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option #1

Use pure CSS3 instead. Look into using CSS animations rather than queueing them up with Javascript. It is kind of pointless with modern browsers. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) and [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

## Option #2

You'll have to set a timeout to delay the execution of the second jQuery line. Like so:

```
jQuery("#topbar").css({transition: "background-color 10s ease", background: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)"});

setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery("#topbar").css({
        background: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)"}
    );
}, 10000);
```

Now if you want them to loop you'll have to set up a recursive relation between the two functions. Hope this helps!

Comment: True! Oversight on my part

Comment: There are options three and four - use `$.queue` or `$.animate` so that it can be `$.dequeue`d or `$.stop`ped easily.

Comment: Worked a treat. I'll look into CSS animations.

Comment: You can also listen for `transitionend` (`webkitTransitionEnd` is the only prefixed one you'll need) events and chain them that way as well.